# udev, overwrite existing rules

Tags: usb, hid, udev

when I plug an HID device into my Linux box (OpenSuse 15.3), then the UDEV rules in
`/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-input.rules seem` to apply and it gets a `MODE="664"`.

I'd like to handle several HID devices on my own and not have them handled by the generic rule
that already comes with my installations UDEV.

Is there a way to specifically formulate own rules for just some devices (based on VID:PID) so they
overwrite the ones that are already in place?

Thanks for any hints,
Torsten

Answer (score 3):

`systemd-udev` has terrible support for `.rules`, so what you can do depends on your systemd version.

1. The official way that `man udev` suggests, supported by all systemd versions: you basically create a rule file under `/etc/` directory which has same name as the one you wanted to override. Quoting:

   > files with identical filenames replace each other. Files in `/etc/` have the highest priority, files in `/run/` take precedence over files with the same name under `/usr/`. This can be used to override a system-supplied rules file with a local file if needed; a symlink in `/etc/` with the same name as a rules file in `/usr/lib/`, pointing to `/dev/null`, disables the rules file entirely.

   So in your case you have to copy `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-input.rules` to `/etc/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-input.rules`, then you edit lines you're interested in and add your custom handling of `ATTRS{idVendor}=="NUMBER1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="NUMBER2"`. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/183492/59928).
2. Unofficial way, which I recommend: create a `.rules` with priority `99` that undoes whatever systemd did. It's the best solution, because the alternative from point `1.` means you may get into trouble on a system update, which may change content of the system rules as well as their names, so your overrides would just silently break.

   Well, implementing that is hard: did I mention `systemd-udev` is broken? Well, here's number of upstream bugs that will be in your way: [`-=` didn't work](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/9463#issuecomment-414938287) until [v253](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/26081), the [`=` doesn't work](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/9463#issuecomment-1241729820).

   What you can do is create a rule that uses `RUN` command to undo whatever systemd done, but [older systemd versions are prone to race-condition with that](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/24607#issuecomment-1241804064). The `250` is known to work though, not sure when exactly they fixed that, so you may have to test that yourself, by using e.g. testcases from the linked bugreport.

Whichever way you chose, detecting VID and PID is done with `ATTRS{idVendor}=="VID"` and `ATTRS{idProduct}=="PID"`